# Efficient data structure to hold/add/remove duplicate items

Tags: java, data-structures, memory-efficient

I have 2 sources from which I read data. That data could be duplicate and I need to detect these duplicates by subtracting the 2 collection from one another.
Currently, I use `List<Map<String, String> duplList`, so when I insert duplicate values:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap();
map1.put("1", "1");
map1.put("1", "1");
map1.put("1", "1");
duplList.add(map1);

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap();
map2.put("1", "1");
map2.put("1", "1");
duplList.add(map2);
```

And later subtract them:

```
Collection diff1 = CollectionUtils.subtract(map1, map2);
Collection diff2 = CollectionUtils.subtract(map2, map1);
```

I get an object that contains the difference between map1 and map2.
While this works, It doesn't seem quite efficient to me (as it runs in O(n) time).
I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to add and subtract data to a more efficient data structure.

Comment: How do you define duplicates? Duplicate keys or key-value pairs? Also, how do you resolve conflicts after the duplicates have been found?

Comment: If I understand you right you can add your "duplicable" objects to Set using add method. If call of add with an object returns false then the object is duplicate, so store it to separate collection.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev Duplicates are defined as the same key-value paris, so "1"->"1" is a duplicate, but "1"->"2" is not.

Comment: If by "difference" you mean that you want a list of items that don't appear in *both* sets, then the best you can do is O(n). Some data structures will be more efficient than others, which will reduce constant factors, but asymptotically you can't do better than O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your data in an unsorted Collection, you can use `HashSet`, if you want it sorted you can use `TreeSet`. `TreeSet` requires a class which implements `Comparable` though - if you just work with strings or integers, you should be fine. You can find more information at [Java Doc: Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: I failed to mention that my data must be in key-value pair format. Will it be more efficient to store it in Set<Map<String, String>> than a List<Map<String, String>>?